# java.net.URI cannot parse domain starting with a number

Tags: java, uri

I have a URI, `http://my-host.1domain:1234/path`, that throws a `URISyntaxException` using one URI constructor:

```java
new URI("http", /*userInfo*/null, /*host*/"my-host.1domain", 1234, "/path", /*query*/null, /*fragment*/null);

Exception in thread "main" java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 15: http://my-host.1domain:1234/path
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2974)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHostname(URI.java:3517)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(URI.java:3358)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3277)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3219)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3175)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:708)
```

but parses correctly using a different URI constructor:

```java
// parses correctly
new URI("http", /*authority*/"my-host.1domain:1234", "/path", /*query*/null, /*fragment*/null);
```

Tested in OpenJDK 17.0.1.  I've checked that [domain names can start with a digit](https://serverfault.com/questions/638260/is-it-valid-for-a-hostname-to-start-with-a-digit).  So am I misusing the URI constructor or is this a bug?

(Background: the failing constructor is called from `UriComponentsBuilder` in Spring Web, who closed this as [not-a-bug in their code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27733))

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8188305 seems to be the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example `1domain` is a TLD (top level domain). If to look at [this spec](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-liman-tld-names-00.html) it states:

> A TLD label MUST be at least two characters long and MAY be as long as 63 characters - not counting any leading or trailing periods (.). It MUST consist of only ASCII characters from the groups "letters" (A-Z), "digits" (0-9) and "hyphen" (-), **and it MUST start with an ASCII "letter"**, and it MUST NOT end with a "hyphen". Upper and lower case MAY be mixed at random, since DNS lookups are case-insensitive.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  In that case, why does the second constructor succeed?

Comment: Good question ^) I don't know..

Comment: @hertzsprung The second constructor does not parse the authority.  Calling [parseServerAuthority](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#parseServerAuthority()) after construction will generate the exception you expect.

Comment: @VGR looks like you're right!  But the javadoc for the authority-based constructor states: "The resulting URI string is then parsed as if by invoking the URI(String) constructor and then invoking the parseServerAuthority() method upon the result; this may cause a URISyntaxException to be thrown".  Which seems to contradict the observed behaviour.

Comment: @hertzsprung I agree, it appears to be a bug.  Although, based on the link in Kayaman’s comment, I think the bug is that all constructors should allow domain labels to start with a digit.